# iPhone 6S will not charge to 100%

Tags: battery, charging, iphone

My iPhone 6S will not charge to 100%. I have iOS version 10.0.2 right now but I'm pretty sure it has been like this for older versions. It also usually powers off before it reaches 0% (sometimes as high as 30%) so maybe that has something to do with it.

I just downloaded http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery to see if that might give any insight.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: You say that it won't charge to 100%, then you say it shuts off early. Which is it, or is it both?

Comment: Really both, but because I've seen questions about the low battery I'm framing this from the battery-not-charging angle instead :)

Comment: Sounds like your battery is out of calibration, meaning the system can't determine the min and max range of charge for the battery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A batch of Apple's iPhone 6s models had a problem where battery reaches about 30% and switches off. This was due to a battery defect and they have opened a scheme for those affected consumers to get the battery replaced. It's not a software problem, it's a manufacturing defect.

For more info: [iPhone 6s Program for Unexpected Shutdown Issues](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone6s-unexpectedshutdown/).

Comment: Apple replaced my phone without any hassle. Oddly, though, they gave my friend the runaround and he had the same phone and same issue.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 10.1.1 is out now, so update to it, even though you said the problem persisted through older software updates, it can't hurt.

If a software update doesn't help, you probably need to recalibrate your battery:

1. Charge fully (without using it)
2. Use it until your battery is completely dead
3. Charge fully again (without using it)
4. Do a hard restart by holding the both the home button and power button down until you get the Apple logo.